# Ajax Request Doesn't Work In Live Google Play App

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, google-play, phonegap

I have a Phonegap app. It works perfect in debug and apk file that phonegap gives. But when I upload to Google Play and download from here my ajax requests doesn't work. I added permissions and

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in config.xml but the problem isn't fixed.

My ajax lines are:

```js
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            var radioValue = $("input[name='optradio']:checked").val();
            if ($('input.refakat').is(':checked')) {
                var ref = "1";
            }
            else {
                var ref = "0";
            }
            // alert(radioValue);
            $.get( "https://example.com/api.php?barkod&id2="+result.text+"&ogun="+radioValue+"&ref="+ref+"&session="+localStorage.getItem("session"), function( data ) {
                $( ".result" ).html( data );
                // alert( "Load was performed." );
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Play App Signing your APK will be signed with a different key that comes from Google Play. I suspect your AJAX requests are on a server that checks APK certificate signing key for the requests. If you register the Google Play certificate hash it should work. See [the documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) in the section

- opt in a new app
- Step 3: Register your app signing key with API providers